# Scrapy import error: No module named items

Tags: python, scrapy, importerror

I set-up my project using

```
scrapy startproject can411
```

so the `__init__.py` files are present.

This is the code within my spider canada_411Spider.py 
(not named the same as the project folder)

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from can411.items import Can411Item
```

When I try to import Can411Item throws a module not found error. (Yes items.py file exists and has class named Can411Item)

I can fix the prob by editing the PYTHONPATH var to include

```
"C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0;F:\TOOLS\Python Development\ScrapyWork\can411"
```

Just this seems like a extremely bad way of fixing my problem. Any items how to better fix this without hard-coding the path into the environment settings?

file structure is:

```
F:\TOOLS\Python Development\ScrapyWork\can411\can411\spiders
```

Answer (score 0):

The files should be called `__init__.py` not `__init.py__`.

What does your directory structure look like?

```
dirbot/
├── dirbot
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── spiders
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── dmoz.py
├── README.rst
├── scrapy.cfg
└── setup.py
```

Also, maybe you could include the full stacktrace error output along with the command-line you are using.

Comment: Type, my bad. Yes the file structure looks like the example you gave.

Comment: Can you please include the file structure in your question, you might have a conflict with `can411`.